# Gnome-Terminal PopOS

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnome-terminal, pop-os

So i `sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-terminal` and installed alacritty. After that I checked for updates, after that I did `sudo apt-get full-upgrade` and PopOS installed Xterm. Why did this happen? The icon for Xterm also had "5050" over-laying the icons png image.

Comment: Why the "bash" and "ubuntu" tags?

Comment: How did you install `alacritty`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `apt-get full-upgrade` will install `Xterm`, as it may be included in default packages.

Also:

```
full-upgrade (apt-get(8))
   full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole.
```